# Gitlab Auto DevOps ingress endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-ingress, gitlab-autodevops

I am trying to configure CI on Kubernetes with Gitlab and Google Cloud and I'm stuck on Let's Encrypt certificate creation. I have 2 clusters for 2 environments:

1. Environment scope: `production` - for production instance
2. Environment scope: `*` - for staging and review instances

After deployment I have configured an Ingress service with endpoint which I declared: `staging.my-domain.com` and second one which is a mystery for me: `le-23830502.my-domain.com`. That second host is equal in two environment - staging and production and when I'm trying to generate certificates I can do it only for one environment (because on second one acme challenge will never pass, because I can't point on DNS two different ip addresses on one subdomain).

Anyone know what is that host? Where is configured and can I disable it or make it unique on different environments?

I notice that is my project id from gitlab with `le-` prefix. I found also 2 environment variables (`$ADDITIONAL_HOSTS` and `$ENVIRONMENT_ADDITIONAL_HOSTS`) for adding another host addresses for Ingress but that one is still there.

Staging deployment:

```
RESOURCES:
==> v1/Deployment
NAME     READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
staging  1/1    1           1          6d3h
==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                      READY  STATUS       RESTARTS  AGE
staging-69d9fb68cc-85prp  1/1    Running      0         13s
staging-744bfc8cc5-jc5w9  1/1    Terminating  0         22h
==> v1/Service
NAME                 TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)   AGE
staging-auto-deploy  ClusterIP  10.116.8.120  <none>       3030/TCP  6d3h
==> v1beta1/Ingress
NAME                 CLASS   HOSTS                                              ADDRESS        PORTS    AGE
staging-auto-deploy  <none>  staging.my-domain.com,le-23830502.my-domain.com    34.121.X.X     80, 443  6d3h
```

Prod deployment:

```
RESOURCES:
==> v1/Deployment
NAME        READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
production  1/1    1           1          26h
==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                         READY  STATUS       RESTARTS  AGE
production-77d9fbdf45-ps6xg  0/1    Terminating  6         10m
production-c7849868f-djhhk   1/1    Running      0         18s
==> v1/Service
NAME                    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)   AGE
production-auto-deploy  ClusterIP  10.27.15.197  <none>       3030/TCP  26h
==> v1beta1/Ingress
NAME                    CLASS   HOSTS                                           ADDRESS      PORTS    AGE
production-auto-deploy  <none>  prod.my-domain.com,le-23830502.my-domain.com    34.69.X.X    80, 443  26h
```

.gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
include:
  - template: Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

test:
  variables:
    DB_URL: "mongodb://mongo:27017/kubernetes-poc-app"
  services:
    - name: mongo:4.4.3
      alias: mongo
  stage: test
  image: gliderlabs/herokuish:latest
  needs: []
  script:
    - cp -R . /tmp/app
    - /bin/herokuish buildpack test
  rules:
    - if: '$TEST_DISABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'

.production: &production_template
  extends: .auto-deploy
  stage: production
  script:
    - auto-deploy check_kube_domain
    - auto-deploy download_chart
    - auto-deploy ensure_namespace
    - auto-deploy initialize_tiller
    - auto-deploy create_secret
    - auto-deploy deploy
    - auto-deploy delete canary
    - auto-deploy delete rollout
    - auto-deploy persist_environment_url
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://prod.$KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN
  artifacts:
    paths: [environment_url.txt, tiller.log]
    when: always

production:
  <<: *production_template
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE == null || $CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE == ""'
      when: never
    - if: '$STAGING_ENABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$CANARY_ENABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$INCREMENTAL_ROLLOUT_ENABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$INCREMENTAL_ROLLOUT_MODE'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'

staging:
  extends: .auto-deploy
  stage: staging
  variables:
    DATABASE_URL: "here should be url"
    DATABASE_NAME: "here should be name"
  script:
    - auto-deploy check_kube_domain
    - auto-deploy download_chart
    - auto-deploy ensure_namespace
    - auto-deploy initialize_tiller
    - auto-deploy create_secret
    - auto-deploy deploy
    - auto-deploy persist_environment_url
  artifacts:
    paths: [ environment_url.txt, tiller.log ]
    when: always
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://staging.$KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE == null || $CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE == ""'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "develop"'
      when: never
    - if: '$STAGING_ENABLED'

review:
  extends: .auto-deploy
  stage: review
  script:
    - auto-deploy check_kube_domain
    - auto-deploy download_chart
    - auto-deploy ensure_namespace
    - auto-deploy initialize_tiller
    - auto-deploy create_secret
    - auto-deploy deploy
    - auto-deploy persist_environment_url
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: http://review.$KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN
    on_stop: stop_review
  artifacts:
    paths: [environment_url.txt, tiller.log]
    when: always
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE == null || $CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE == ""'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
      when: never
    - if: '$REVIEW_DISABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true

stop_review:
  extends: .auto-deploy
  stage: cleanup
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - auto-deploy initialize_tiller
    - auto-deploy delete
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    action: stop
  allow_failure: true
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE == null || $CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE == ""'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
      when: never
    - if: '$REVIEW_DISABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      when: manual
```

Comment: Hello, could you tell more about how exactly have you deployed your Gitlab (`Helm` or other sources)? Do I assume correctly that you are using `GKE`?

Comment: @dawid-kruk I am using standard Auto DevOps templates from Gitlab. I have added 2 kubernetes clusters from Google Cloud to Gitlab `Operations->Kubernetes`. Applications are deployed by CI pipeline.
Here is the chart for autodeploy: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/auto-deploy-app

Comment: I think the number 23830502 is the id of your Gitlab project. No idea how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the le-1234567 domain that is added, you need to modify the ingress.yaml template.

You can find it here:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/-/blob/master/assets/auto-deploy-app/templates/ingress.yaml

You can fork the project, and build new images, or you can follow the guidelines of adding your own chart here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#custom-helm-chart

Here is an example of how I modified it for my rails apps:
https://gitlab.com/leifcr/auto-deploy-image-rails/-/blob/master/assets/auto-deploy-app/templates/ingress.yaml

If you have multiple projects that all need the same config, I recommend changing the image to fit your needs. If you only have one, add a bundled chart.